# Why does grep with the -c option always show 0 over ssh

Tags: bash, grep

I have a script on three different servers. The basics are that script checks for a certain file on its system and if the file is not there then it will ssh to the other servers and run the same script. The check is run via;

`If [[ $(ls ${folder} | grep -c ${file}) -gt 0 ]]; then "do stuff with the files"; else "ssh to other server and check again"; fi`

It wasnt giving output when the information was on a remote server. So I ran the check on a server I knew had the files and it worked. However when i would  try and run it remotely, the file count would be 0.

I changed it from grep to wc -l and then it worked. I'm wondering if anybody knows why grep -c works locally but with ssh

Comment: Exactly how are you running it remotely? Depending on how you do it, it might be running part or all of the checks locally instead of remotely.

Answer (score 1):

It 'if' doesn't work like that.
If you want to check the existence of a file, you must use this:

```
[ -f ${file} ]
```